# How to execute a formula in Excel 2007 within a formula

Tags: excel

[image]

How to **code** this:

```
if value of a cell A1 = "C" then calculate formula for Commercial Rate 
if value of a cell A1 = "R" then calculate formula for Residential Rate 
else ""
```

How to run this in a single formula for a single cell?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Excel 2007 maximum number of nested IFs was 7. From 2007 onwards it is 64.

So if you have excel 2007 or later, the formula below should work:

```
=IF(A1="C",IF(L29="",0,IF(M29<=10,375,IF(AND(M29>10,M29<=20),375+(M29-10)*39,IF(AND(M29>30,M29<40),375+390+(M29-20)*41.25,IF(AND(M29>30,M29<=40),375+390+413+(M29-30)*43.5,375+390+413+435+(M29-40)*45.75))))),IF(A1="R",IF(O32="",0,IF(P32<=10,250,IF(AND(P32>10,P32<=20),250+(P32-10)*26,IF(AND(P32>20,P32<30),250+260+(P32-20)*27.5,IF(AND(P32>30,P32<=40),250+260+275+(P32-30)*29,250+260+275+290+(P32-40)*30.5))))),""))
```

Please note that your formulas might work but they do not follow modeling best practices. Best practices say that shorter formulas are better because they are easier to understand, easier to audit and easier to modify. Best practices also say that you should avoid hard-coded numbers inside formulas and they should instead have their own input cells.

Comment: thank you its working .. its just that im really new at this

Comment: @MTO You can find a description of best practices here: [link](https://www.wallstreetprep.com/knowledge/financial-modeling-best-practices-and-conventions/#Formulas)